# How to find the nearest element in a list

Tags: python, list, lambda

I want to find the element of a given index and the element near to it from a large python list like this:

```
list = ['askdjh', 'afgld', 'asf' ,'asd', '623gfash', 'fhd', 'hfdjs']
```

And I chose 'asd' :

```
number = 4
item near it = 623gfash
```

Comment: Please, show the code you have tried, so we can help you.

Comment: What's should happen if the target is the last number, `'hfdjs'` in your example?

Comment: I think it should print out of near objects but still to print its pos

Comment: What do you need that position for? Notice that python indexes from 0, not from 1. So, despite `'asd'` is the 4th item, it's index is 3.

Comment: Yes, but which one would be the "near object" of the last item? In your example, the near object is the next one. There's no _next one_ after the last one.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use

```
pos = my_list.index('asd')
nearest = my_list[pos + 1]
```

Note pos is 3 for the 4th element as Python is 0- based. Note avoid using list for variables as this name has a special meaning in Python.

Comment: It is worth adding a check to see if this element is the last one, so as not to go beyond the list: if pos+1<len(my_list):

Answer (score -1):

Try below

```
ind=ls.index("asd")
if ind<len(ls)-1:
   print(f"{ind}",ls.__getitem__(ind+1))
else:
   print(f"{ind}", ls.__getitem__(ind - 1))
```

ind, will give you the index of the chosen obj, and using that index only you can fetch closest obj by adding or subtracting 1 from the "ind"